# Langchain add memory to gmail agent

Tags: python, agent, langchain, large-language-model

Seems like doing this isn't adding memory to the agent properly:

```py
from langchain.prompts import MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
agent_kwargs = {
    "extra_prompt_messages": [MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="memory")],
}
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="memory", return_messages=True)

agent = initialize_agent(
    tools=tools,
    llm=llm,
    agent=AgentType.STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, memory=memory, agent_kwargs=agent_kwargs, verbose=True
)
```

On my second request it's doing a completely differnt gmail query. Any idea why?

I exepected my agent to have at least short-term memory

Answer (score 0):

[documentation to add memory in STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION agent](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/structured_chat#adding-in-memory)

```
from langchain.prompts import MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

chat_history = MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history")
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

agent_chain = initialize_agent(
    tools, 
    llm, 
    agent=AgentType.STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, 
    verbose=True, 
    memory=memory, 
    agent_kwargs = {
        "memory_prompts": [chat_history],
        "input_variables": ["input", "agent_scratchpad", "chat_history"]
    }
)

response = await agent_chain.arun(input="Hi I'm Erica.")
print(response)
```